# How to set Focus after calling MessageBox from a Dialog?

Tags: wxpython

With wxPython I would like to do the following:

- create a Frame
- call a Dialog (from that Frame)
- call a MessageBox (from that Dialog)
- click "ok" on the MessageBox
- afterwards the focus should be on the Dialog

Instead the Dialog remains in the foreground, but the focus is on the Frame!

I use this software:

- wxPython: 4.1.0 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.4
- Python: Python 3.8.10
- OS: 5.4.0-90-generic #101-Ubuntu

Here is a little sample program:

```
import wx


class Dialog1(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, name='', parent=parent,
              pos=wx.Point(500, 100), size=wx.Size(500, 200),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE, title='My Dialog')
                
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "open MessageBox")
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.DisplayMessage)
        box.Add(button1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        
        self.orderNr = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=0, value='')
        box.Add(self.orderNr, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(box)
        self.Layout()
        
        
    def DisplayMessage(self, event):
        #wx.MessageBox('Important Message')
        wx.MessageBox('Important Message', parent=self)
        self.orderNr.SetFocus()
        #event.Skip()
        
        
class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 200))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        m_text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Hello World!")
        box.Add(m_text, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        button1 = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "open Dialog")
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OpenDialog)
        box.Add(button1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        
        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Layout()


    def OpenDialog(self, event):
        dialog1 = Dialog1(self)
        dialog1.ShowModal()
        #event.Skip()


app = wx.App(None)
top = Frame("My Frame")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You don't say what version of `wxPython` you are using but on Linux with `'4.1.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5'` it clearly works as required i.e. once the messagebox has been dismissed, the `self.orderNr.SetFocus()` selects the TextCtrl in the Dialog and the next keyboard input is in that control.

Comment: Hi Rolf, thanks, that helps for a start :)
I use this version: 4.1.0 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.4
I will update the original post.

Comment: ok, I have tried, with the 4.1.1 Version, but this does not work here either. 
@RolfofSaxony: which Python version do you use?

Comment: Works for me as well. I suspect the problem itself is not in wxPython but in the OS's window manager.

Comment: That could be. I use Xfce 4.14 (xfwm4 for window manager). 
I will try with a different one later.

Comment: Yes! On my other PCs it works: Kubuntu with KDE Plasma (5.12.9)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround: it works, when I hide and show the Dialog:

```
    def DisplayMessage(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox('Important Message')
        self.Hide()
        self.Show()
        self.orderNr.SetFocus()
```

Comment: How about `self.Refresh()`? It looks like the window manager needs a gentle nudge, as Petr points out.

Comment: no, that does not help :-/